# Is it required to use android mobile to develop an android application

Tags: android, mobile

I wonder that is it necessary to use android mobile to build an android powered application.
Actually i'm developing an android music application. I used emulator only to test the app. Is there any changes happened to the app when i test that with real device or it works same in the both??

Comment: why you dot wonder about using a android app??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can use the default emulator or other tools like [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

You should just consider that a real device might be handy as you get a better feeling of your app when you have it on a real device.

Also there are limitations based on the emulator you use. For example the graphic power might be way slower than on a real device. Also other stuff like battery, camera etc is basically just emulated as well, so it might work on the emulator but not on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same answer if you switched Android for iOS.

It is not required, but it is a very big advantage.

Android and iOS come with emulators for their platforms in the software development kit. So if you want to do quick testing then you don't need a device.

However, if your application relies on any hardware component (for example the accelerometer) these functions are not available in the emulators.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use android emulators instead..

check the below link for more info:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory for development and deployment (publishing to google play store) we can use emulator.

But I strongly recommend to use as development time would fair increase while debugging with actual device rather on emulator.